# Prove that continuous function with some properties maps closed sets to closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$(X,d)$ and $(Y,\delta)$ are metric spaces, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous function.

I know that $K \subseteq Y$ is compact $\Rightarrow f^{-1}(K)\subseteq X$ is compact. Prove that $C \subseteq X$ is closed $\Rightarrow f(C) \subseteq Y$ is closed.

I'm using this definition of closed set: $\ f(C)$ is closed iff $$\forall(y_n)_n \subseteq f(C):y_n\rightarrow\bar y\quad \exists \bar x\in C:f(\bar x)=\bar y \qquad i.e. \quad \bar y \in f(C)$$

I tried:

Let $(y_n)_n \subseteq f(C): y_n \rightarrow \bar y\in Y$

$y_n \in f(C)\; \forall n\in N \Rightarrow \forall n \in N\; \exists x_n \in C : y_n=f(x_n)$

$y_n \rightarrow \bar y \quad i.e. \quad f(x_n)\rightarrow \bar y $

And now I think I have to use the fact that $f$ is continuous but maybe I'm not going anywhere with this proof and I'm wasting time. Help?

Comment: You have to use the property about preimages of compacts somewhere. A compact set in $Y$ naturally arising here would by $\{y_n\}_n\cup\{\bar y\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see that $f$ is closed, let $C \subseteq X$ be closed and we want to show that $f[C]$ is closed. To this end, let $(f(c_n))_n$ be a sequence in $f[C]$ that converges to $y \in Y$. Then define $K = \{f(c_n): n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{y\}$ is compact in $Y$ so by assumption, $f^{-1}[K]$ is compact in $X$ and contains the sequence $(c_n)_n$, which thus has a convergent subsequence $(c_{n_k})_k$ that converges to some $x \in f^{-1}[K]$. But then by closedness of $C$, $x \in C$ and by continuity of $f$, $f(c_{n_k}) \to f(x)$ but also $f(c_{n_k})_k \to y$, as we have a subsequence of $f(c_n)$, and unicity of limits in $Y$ tells us that $y  =f(x) \in f[C]$ and we're done: $f[C]$ is closed.